# Python Get min max betweeen 2 columns across sequence of number

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
id  start  end
1   101    102
1   102    104
1   104    110
1   125    128
2   100    102
2   102    104
2   110    115
```

I want output as:

```
id  start  end
1   101    110
1   125    128
2   100    104
2   110    115
```

Comment: Why is the output in that order?

Comment: I want to remove the unnecessary sequences from the data and just use only one row for the sequential data

Comment: Looks like `end` runs untill index of max from `start`? Could you add your code too please?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any code to resolve it. I am looking for the way to solve.

Comment: Please tell us more details about your problem. Which are the transformations that you would like to perform on your initial set in order to have the output you require? What did you try to do by yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
import numpy as np

a = df[['start', 'end']].values
# check which end is different to the start of the row bellow
m = (a[:-1] != a[1:,::-1]).all(1)
# array([False, False,  True,  True, False,  True])
# Take the cumsum and use it to group the df rows
g = np.cumsum(np.r_[False, m])
# array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3], dtype=int32)
# group the df and take the first an last sample accordingly
out = df.groupby(g).agg({'id':'first', 'start':'first', 'end':'last'})
```

---

```
print(out)

   id  start  end
0   1    101  110
1   1    125  128
2   2    100  104
3   2    110  115
```

Comment: Thank You ! It worked. However it had minor issue it was failing for a case where IDs were different yet end time and start time were in sequence. So I added comparison for the ID as well and it worked.